Proving $\|v\|^2 \ge \sum _{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle^2$
Prove that: $\|v\|^2 \ge  \sum _{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle^2$ for any $v \in  V$, where $V$ is an inner product space and $S = \{e_1, e_2, \ldots , e_n\}$ is an orthonormal subset of $V$.
I know from the decomposition theorem that
\begin{align*}
u &=  \langle u, e_1\rangle^2 e_1+ \cdots + \langle u, e_n\rangle^2 e_n \\
\|u\|^2 &=  \langle u, e_1\rangle^2 + \cdots + \langle u, e_n\rangle^2  = \sum _{i=1}^n \langle u,e_i\rangle^2.
\end{align*}
My issue is, how can I get the inequality sign and prove the statement?
EDIT: what if $v \in$ span(S)? How can I show that the inequality becomes an equality?

$S$ can be extended to a  orthonormal basis on V,note$S'$ and $|S|\leq|S'|$

You have $v=\sum_k \langle e_k v \rangle e_k + w$, where $w \bot e_k$. Hence $|v|^2 = \sum_k  |\langle e_k v \rangle|^2 + |w|^2$.

For a proof which does not require extension to a basis just expand $|v- \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \langle v, e_i \rangle|^{2}$.

@copper.hat Thanks for the comment. I am not exactly sure why that is true, where did you get $w$ and why did you add $w$

It was a hint, not an answer. How could you define $w$?

What if $v$ isn't in the span of $S$?  Then the sum of inner products can't "recover" all of $v$.

With all due respect, why is there a bounty on this? This is standard (Alt - Linear Functional Analysis, 9.6)

@copper.hat, yes but can you explain why v = sum of k $<e_k, v> e_k + w?$ you said I have this but I not really sure the summation part, for $w$ maybe orthogonal projection

@CountDOOKU I added an answer.

We have:
$$0\leq||v-\sum_i<v,e_i>e_i||^2=<v-\sum_i<v,e_i>e_i , v-\sum_j<v,e_j>e_j>\,=||v||^2-2\sum_i<v,e_i>^2+\sum_i<v,e_i>^2 =||v||^2-\sum_i<v,e_i>^2 $$by the linear of inner product and Orthogonality property

Thanks but what if $v \in$ span(S)? How can I show that the inequality becomes an equality?

@CountDOOKU You can see in the left of my proof. If $v\in span(S)$, then $v=\sum_i<v,e_i>e_i$. So it is a zero. That is when the inequality becomes an equality.
